# Normalize a string which contains a decimal to specific CultureInfo.NumberFormat

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, decimal, cultureinfo

I'm struggling trying to normalize a number to an specific `CultureInfo`, applying its `NumberFormat`

Let's say I have a string which also contains some characters, so I need to clean it up:

```
var cleanedInput = Regex.Replace(userInput, @"[^0-9-,'.]+", "");
```

So I'm basically keeping `,` `'` and `.` . I'm doing this because depending on the `CultureInfo`, the `,` and the `.` are differently used to separate decimals or to group the numbers.

Having that in mind, I apply the `Decimal.TryParse` method, specifying the `NumberStyle` to allow decimals and the `IFormatProvider`is going to be dinamically applied to the desired "local" `CultureInfo.NumberFormat`.

```
decimal numericData;
if (!decimal.TryParse(cleanedInput, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, LocaleUser.NumberFormat, out numericData))
    throw new Exception($"Error occurred. Could not parse:{cleanedInput} ");
```

Let's say we input `"hi9000,99hi"`. Once cleaned, we get `"9000,99"`. Nice.
So then, we apply the `TryParse` and it returns `Decimal` `9000.99`. Important saying that I'm actually applying the `es-ES` `CultureInfo` which has the `,` as decimal separator. I'm basically expecting `9000,99` or `9.000,99` .

The code is not raising the `Exception`, but looks like it's not applying the `CultureInfo` I specified.

What am I exactly missing? I have the feeling that `Decimal.TryParse` is a swiss army knife that I'm handling well.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but remember that a decimal does not _have_ a format. You supply a format when _displaying_ the value - if you're looking at it in the debugger then it will use whatever culture your machine is set to. If you want to see the value in a specific format then use `decimal.ToString` or `string.Format`.

Comment: So to clarify, the code you provide is raising an exception? And  `cleanedInput` is what you expect prior to going into the parser?

Comment: Thanks for replying you all. The code is not raising the Exception, but the output I'm getting is definetely not applying the CultureInfo I specified and not even the CultureInfo which is using the VS2015 where it's being debugged.

Comment: @Gonzo345 Again, just because you _parse_ a string using a culture doesn't mean that the resulting value will always be _displayed_ in that culture.  You either have to specify a culture when you convert to a string or the culture of the system will be used.

Comment: What _output_ are you talking about? Not you `numericData`, I hope? because that has no decimal seperator like a `.` or ','. If you want to _display_ that value as a formatted string, use the locale of your choice and it will be fine. The locale you use to parse means that a Spanish user can _input_ "999,99", whereas an American would get an error with that same input. You are telling TryParse to _treat_ the input as if it is written in that locale so it can understand it correctly.

Comment: The code is working perfectly.  You are not getting an exception and getting the correct decimal value.  Parsing converts a string to a number (or DateTime).  What you see in VS is the results using you PC settings so the if you are in the USA you will see the decimal value while debugging in US format.

Comment: I finally get what you meant @DStanley ! So a decimal is a decimal and it has no format. It's just formatted once you output it on your machine and it depends on the CultureInfo which is applying!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using double.Parse, decimal.Parse or decimal.TryParse seems to work.  How was the CultureInfo defined?

```
string value = "9000,99";
decimal number;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");

try {
    number = decimal.Parse(value, culture);
    decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, culture, out decimal num);
    Console.WriteLine($"{culture.Name}: {value} = {number} / {num}");                       
} catch (FormatException) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{culture.Name}: Unable to parse [{value}]");
}
```

Output:

```
es-ES: 9000,99 = 9000.99 / 9000.99
```

Comment: I finally got what I was doing wrong, and it was interpreting the final output, which was "modified" by my actual machine's CultureInfo. BTW, the CultureInfo was specified by a prop :)

Answer (score 0):

So, given that a Decimal will always be a Decimal and has no format, as on the comments has been stated, I was incorrectly focusing the questions and what was I searching for!

I'm finally using this method:

```
private decimal CleanUserInput(string userInput, CultureInfo localeUser)
{
    if (localeUser == null)
        throw new Exception("A CultureInfo must be specified. ");

    var cleanedInput = Regex.Replace(userInput, @"[^0-9-,\.']+", "");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cleanedInput))
        throw new Exception("Data provided has no numbers to be parsed. ");

    decimal numericData;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(cleanedInput, NumberStyles.Any, localeUser, out numericData))
        throw new Exception($"Couldn't parse {cleanedInput} . Make sure the applied CultureInfo ({LocaleUser.DisplayName}) is the correct one. Decimal separator to be applied: <{LocaleUser.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}> Numeric group separator to be applied: <{LocaleUser.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator}>");

    return numericData;
}
```